# row bind matrices, zero out all rows but one

Tags: r, matrix

Given a matrix

```
a <- matrix(c(15,2,11,16,7,12,1,8,3), nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow=T)
```

I'd like to row bind three copies of the matrix, but in each copy all rows but one should have zero values. The desired result:

```
 15    2   11
  0    0    0
  0    0    0
  0    0    0
 16    7   12
  0    0    0
  0    0    0
  0    0    0
  1    8    3
```

I can do this by `rbind(a[1,],0,0,0,a[2,],0,0,0,a[3,])`, but is there a better way when dealing with a large matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
matrix(t(cbind(a,matrix(0,3,9))),ncol=3,byrow=T)[1:9,]
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]   15    2   11
 [2,]    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0
 [5,]   16    7   12
 [6,]    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0
 [8,]    0    0    0
 [9,]    1    8    3
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
apply(a, 2, function(r) rbind(r, matrix(rep(0,9), nrow=3)))[1:9, ]
```

> ```
>       [,1] [,2] [,3]
>  [1,]   15    2   11
>  [2,]    0    0    0
>  [3,]    0    0    0
>  [4,]    0    0    0
>  [5,]   16    7   12
>  [6,]    0    0    0
>  [7,]    0    0    0
>  [8,]    0    0    0
>  [9,]    1    8    3
> ```